# PHP: Appending objects in OOP?

Tags: php, oop

I've transitioned my coding step by step into OOP, which feels great. What I haven't got a hold of yet, is when It's time to use an object and when to use the conventional arrays.

Let's say that I would have the following code. Here we create an array containing Persons -  receivers of emails. It's really cute, but it feels kind of smelly to jump back and forwards between arrays and objects.

Are my concerns legitimate or is this good  practice?

```
public function receiver($email, $name = FALSE) {

    $person = new Person();
    $person->email = $email;
    $person->name = $name;

    $this->receiver[] = $person;
}
```

Comment: Seems good to me. You can't avoid using array's even in OOP. You might want to change your naming conventions though. I mean public function addReciever would be cleaner IMHO. And maybe you can put name and email to constructor, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @Voooza I was actually about to say that.

Comment: @Vooza Thanks - this was just a quick mock up to show the idea of jumping cross datatypes and show my point. I agree that it could be organized better, but it isn't going into production anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's absolutely fine, OOP doesn't preclude using arrays where appropriate.

Comment: Hi! But can I build lists out of objects without arrays?

Comment: @Industrial, yes it's good practice. Sometimes arrays are wrapped in objects (using the ArrayAccess interface) to provide extra functionality but when you just want a list, plain old arrays are best.

Comment: Totally. In classic OOP, that's referred to as a Linked List. It's an object that knows what the next thing in the list is. Doubly Linked Lists will be the same, except they know what the item before them was too. [Linked Lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)

Comment: @Industrial The PHP SPL provides a handful of common datastructure classes that you can use. http://us.php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php

Comment: @Industrial, irrelevant and very minor nitpick - `true`, `false` and `null` are conventionally written in lowercase in PHP to distinguish them from userland constants which are conventionally all uppercase.

Comment: @Lacking Beers: Thanks - that's good to know. I've made it a bad habit to write them in uppercase!

Answer (score 3):

To answer your exact question, yes, using arrays is fine.  You *could* use something like [SplObjectStorage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php) instead, but for most use-cases, an array is quite fine...

I would do this differently.  Instead of creating the object inside the method, I'd pass the object in:

```
public function receiver(Person $person) {
    $this->receiver[] = $person;
}
```

Then calling with:

```
$person = new Person();
$person->email = 'email@example.com';
$obj->receiver($person);
```

That way, you're decoupling the implementation of the `Person` object from the current object (whetever it is).  Even better would be to declare an interface depending on how you expect it to work for that usage, and require an implementation of that interface:

```
interface iEmailable {
    public function getName();
    public function getEmail();
}
class Person implements iEmailable {
    protected $name = '';
    protected $email = '';
    public function __construct($name, $email) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->email = $email;
    }
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

then, adjust your method to:

```
public function receiver(iEmailable $person) {
    $this->receiver[] = $person;
}
```

Now, you're much more decoupled from the concrete `Person` class.  Any class is free to be passed in, as long as it implements the proper interface...

Answer (score 1):

In fact, arrays are often found hiding in OOP objects. The goal of classes/objects is to describe the properties of something. If that something needs to store multiple values of the same type, then there totally could be an array in there.

For instance, a class describing a Car/Automobile, might have an array that stores Seats.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing **wrong** with arrays, and if you have that idea then it is possible that you can "over-objectify" your code.  Some things just don't make sense to create an object for.

In your example, it looks like your object has a property called `receiver`, as well as  a method called `receiver`.  That isn't the best of practices... keep your method and property names distinct.

As for arrays and objects and whatnot, look in to the [`Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) (click for docs) interface.  This allows you to treat an object like an array in `foreach` loops and the like.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on the structure of the code. I just mocked up a quick example to show my point here regarding jumping between data types when storing data..